# Python 2.7 Regular Expressions with a txt file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text-files

I'm working on Python 2.7 and regular expressions. So my question is: how can I select the words with all the letters are uppercase from a .txt file? For example my txt file:

> PYTHON 111 Python I - blabla. JAVA 222 Physics II - blalba..

I want an output like "PYTHON, JAVA".
Also I don't want one letter words in my output.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read about regex? Is the problem the file I/O or writing the regex? Do you know about character classes? If not, why not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Do you care about supporting Unicode? If so, what locales do you plan to support?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions.  Of course if you like them, they can work, but python provides a simpler way:

```
>>> words = "PYTHON 111 Python I - blabla. JAVA 222 APPhysics II - blalba.."
>>> for word in words.split():
...   if word.isalpha() and word.isupper() and len(word) > 1:
...       print word
... 
PYTHON
JAVA
II
```

Comment: Splitting on whitespace is not good enough. For example this won't work with `"JAVA."`.

Comment: @AlexHall good points.  I updated.

Comment: You still need to deal with punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s="PYTHON 111 Python I - blabla. JAVA 222 APPhysics II - blalba.."
>>> re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]{2,}\b", s)
['PYTHON', 'JAVA', 'II']
```

Comment: you just provided a fish, it is more useful if you make an attempt to teach them how to fish. [fish saying](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)  I.E. explain how your solution actually works and what the regex pattern means, instead of just the code to accomplish the task.

Comment: thanks for the answer can you explain what is the use of (r "...")

Comment: r" means raw string.  So you don't have to escape the \

Comment: @Pythonoob34 that's called a raw string. It's not strictly a regex concept but it's useful for that. Otherwise I would have had to write `re.findall("\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b", s)` which is uglier, the difference being the double slash.